# Python networkX MultiDiGraph number of edges

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a directed graph `G` of type `MultiDiGraph` from `networkx` package.

The numbers from below two calls are different. Aren't they supposed to be the same?

`G.number_of_edges()`

`networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G).nnz`

---

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this problem in small graphs that I manually create, as shown in below example where the two calls print the same number 5:

```
import networkx as nx
tmp = nx.MultiDiGraph([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (1, 0), (3, 4)])

tmp.number_of_edges(): 5, nx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(tmp).nnz: 5
```

while here is the output for `G`:

```
G.number_of_edges(): 87780, nx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G).nnz: 84242
```

`G` is a huge graph that someone else generated and I cannot share here.

Comment: Got a reproducible example?

Comment: Unfortunately no -- I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MultiDiGraph` can have multiple edges between the same two nodes.

The `nnz` attribute of the `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` returns the number of non-empty matrix values. If a graph has multiple edges between two nodes, then the value of `nnz` will be the number of connected nodes in each direction, whereas `.number_of_edges()` will be the total number of edges in the graph. These numbers will be different!

Use the `.sum()` value for the `csr_matrix` if you want to get the total number of edges.

```
import networkx as nx
tmp = nx.MultiDiGraph([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (1, 0), (3, 4)])
tmp.add_edge(3, 4)
tmp.add_edge(3, 4)
tmp.add_edge(3, 4)

nx_edge_count = tmp.number_of_edges()
scipy_nnz = nx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(tmp).nnz
scipy_edge_count = nx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(tmp).sum()

print("Number of edges: {}".format(nx_edge_count))
print("Number of non-zero matrix values: {}".format(scipy_nnz))
print("Sum of sparse matrix values: {}".format(scipy_edge_count))
```

> Number of edges: 8
>
> Number of non-zero matrix values: 5
>
> Sum of sparse matrix values: 8

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. And I realized that the adjacency matrix contains value `n` and not `1` for an edge existing `n` times between the same two nodes.